# How to rotate and position the center object?

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, autodesk-forge, matrix-multiplication

[image]
[image]

I created a toolbox that can rotate and reposition a mesh with an axis in the middle. When I separate rotation and position, then the position will return to the previous one. However this causes rotation not on the mesh. So what I do is use multiply. But this is not what I expected because the mesh position should be where I marked it (not in mesh axis).
How to rotate and position the object so that it remains in the specified position and rotate at that location ?
Here is my code :

```js
const translation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(
  this.valueAOA_X,
  this.valueAOA_Y,
  this.valueAOA_Z
);
const angleRadian = CoordinateConverter.degreeToRadian(
  this.valueAOA_Rotation
);
const rotationAOA = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(angleRadian);   
this.selectedModel.setPlacementTransform(
  rotationAOA.multiply(translation)
);
```

Comment: Why are you working with `Matrix4`? Is there something wrong with using a simple `selectedModel.position.set(x, y, z);` and then `selectedModel.rotation.set(x, y, z);`?

Comment: Because I used Autodesk Forge Scene Builder. So to be able to interact with viewerm I have to use Matrix4.

Comment: Ok, I added the `[autodesk-forge]` tag, hopefully someone from Autodesk's support team will be able to help you with their platform.

Comment: Hi Marquizzo. I fixed it by translation multiply rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by this line:

```
  this.selectedModel.setPlacementTransform(
    translation.multiply(rotationAOA)
  );
```